# zmq round robin lost message PUSH/PULL

Tags: python, zeromq, pyzmq

I try to send 10 messages from one client to two workers. I use PUSH/PULL pattern. I lose a message on 2.

```
python push.py 
message n°0
message n°1
message n°2
message n°3
message n°4
message n°5
message n°6
message n°7
message n°8
message n°9
```

worker 1:

```
python pull.py
Received message n°1
Received message n°4
Received message n°7
```

worker 2:

```
python pull.py
Received message n°0
Received message n°3
Received message n°6
Received message n°9
```

I use python 3, here are my code:

push.py

```
import time
import zmq

context = zmq.Context()
socket = context.socket(zmq.PUSH)
socket.bind("tcp://127.0.0.1:5557")

time.sleep(1)
for i in range(10):
    message = "message n°%d" % i
    print(message)
    socket.send_string(message)
    time.sleep(1)
time.sleep(1)
```

pull.py

```
import zmq

context = zmq.Context()

socket = context.socket(zmq.PULL)
socket.connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:5557")

while True:
    print("Received %s" % socket.recv_string())
```

Maybe I lost option on my socket. Any Help ?

Comment: I've noticed weird message loss when pushing messages too quickly. Try increasing the timeout between the messages. Also, make sure you start the 2 pull workers first. Does that change anything? Edit: In my case I was using pub/sub.

Comment: pub sub works as expected and I don't lost any message. Got this error with PUSH/PULL only

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks correct to me.  I copy/pasted it and could not reproduce the issue.  I tried python 2.7.13 and 3.6.0 on OSX.  Using pyzmq version 4.1.2.

What order are you starting the processes?  (It shouldn't matter.)  Do you lose message 2 on every run?

If you can reproduce it then you may need to try a network sniffer to see what is going on.

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, with python 3.5.2. I start my workers and then my server. With 4 workers, I lost number 3 and 8 (0 1 2 x 4 5 6 7 x 9 ). With 3 workers, I lost number 3 and 7 (0 1 2 x 4 5 6 x 8 9 ). With 2 workers, I lost number 2, 5 and 8 (0 1 x 3 4 x 6 7 x 9). With 1 worker, I got all numbers (0 1 2 x 4 5 6 x 8 9 ). I will tcp dump with wireshark

Comment: I just tried on Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS, python 3.4.3, pyzmq 4.0.4 and I couldn't reproduce the issue there either.  It's very strange -- pls let me know if you figure it out.